# Outlook 2013 Auto Archive

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, archiving

If you have enabled Outlook's Auto Archive function, how do know what day that function will be done next? Is there a place within Outlook's settings that would specify the actual date for the next auto archive function to be done? For example, if you just changed the auto archive setting to auto archive every 3 days on 04/16/15, instead of the previous setting of 30 days, does that mean that the auto archive function will run on 04/19/15? If so, at what time on the 04/19/15, will the auto archive function be done? If you specified to be prompted before any auto archive function will be done, will Outlook wait until you start Outlook on the 19th BEFORE it prompts you to perform the auto archive function? Finally, if you are on vacation or out of the office on the 19th, will Outlook wait for your next start of the Outlook program after the 19th to prompt you for the next auto archive function?

Comment: Thank you for your question.In this case, I am asking about Auto Archive on the Outlook 2013 desktop client which saves to a PST file.

Answer (score 0):

To find the next AutoArchive date and time by performing some calculations. Here is the formula:

```
LastAged + EveryDays * 24 * 60 = Result
```

You can find *LastAged* and *EveryDays* values in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences
```

The *Result* is the next AutoArchive date/time (in minutes since Jan 1, 1601).